# while loop remains running, even with its limit exceeded

Tags: c#, windows, while-loop

i'm writing a custom Windows Setup in C#, but have a problem with it.
Basically, when the application loads, it should search for a file called "Install.Wim" in the "sources" folder at the root of all disks, and show a messagebox with the full path of the first file found. 
i've managed to do it putting a while loop that has a foreach statement inside it.
The While's code is:

```
int filenofound = 0;
string wimpath = "sources\\install.wim"
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

while (filenofound < 1)
{
    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        if (File.Exists(d + wimpath))
        {
        wimDsk = d + wimpath;
        MessageBox.Show("Install.WIM found at " + wimDsk);
        filenofound = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Filefound value: " + filenofound);
        }
    }
}
```

but for some reason, the program show one messagebox for each file found, skipping the While's limit.
I've tried using "filenofound" variable as boolean, same problem; while the variable has true, the while still keeps executing.
Sorry if it's a basic question, i'm noob with this language.

Comment: The loop condition is only checked when it loops. In your case, that's when the `foreach` loop ends.

Comment: you need to `break;` out of the foreach loop if you dont want to loop over each drive

Comment: U don't need the while loop....u need to handle if file is t found on any drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Fail to see the need for the while statement at all, if as you say the goal is to search all directories for the specified file and stop at the first one, why the need to loop again?

This should search and find the file and stop:

```
    //bool bFileFound = false;
    string wimpath = "sources\\install.wim";
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    //while (!bFileFound)
    //{
        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (File.Exists(d + wimpath))
            {
                wimDsk = d + wimpath;
                MessageBox.Show("Install.WIM found at " + wimDsk);
                // bFileFound = true; not needed with break;
                break; // break forces the current loop to exit
            }
        }
    //}
```

If you need the do while loop as in the file may not bee there yet I would use the following code:

```
    bool bFileFound = false;
    int iLoopCount = 0; //remove loop count if you need to keep looking forever.
    string wimpath = "sources\\install.wim";
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    do
    {
        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (File.Exists(d + wimpath))
            {
                wimDsk = d + wimpath;
                MessageBox.Show("Install.WIM found at " + wimDsk);
                bFileFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        iLoopCount++;
        if (!bFileFound)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    } while (!bFileFound && iLoopCount < 100000);
```

Comment: Thanks you! i've used the first method, and worked sucessfully!
I'm using the While loop because don't know that the break funcion was available in the foreach statement, i've learned something today.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get what you're looking for is to use a bit of `System.Linq` to first get a list of the paths you want to search (one for each drive), and then return the first one for which `File.Exists` returns `true`.

We can use the `FirstOrDefault` method, which will return the first one found or `null` if none were found, and then we can test the returned value for `null` to display our message:

```
string wimPath = "sources\\install.wim";

// Select the combined path for each drive then return the first one found (or null)
string fullPath = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    .Select(drive => Path.Combine(drive.ToString(), wimPath))
    .FirstOrDefault(File.Exists);                      

if (fullPath == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Install.WIM not found on any drive");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Install.WIM found at: " + firstPath);
}
```

Note: to use the `Linq` extension methods (`Select` and `FirstOrDefault`), you'll need this `using` statement at the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```